# Initialize mongoDB database with default data using mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I would like to initialize a mongoDB database with default data using mongoose.

For example roles like `admin` and `user`.

```
role: {
   name: "admin",
   description: "Admin role"
}
```

Is there an easy way in mongoose to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative to Jcan's answer is using a pre, althought not as direct as a approach I think it allows more flexability:

```
schema.post('save', function(doc, next) {
   this.toJSON().name = 'Default';
};);
```

this is a proof of concept code snippet youd have to probably error fix but you get the idea, you can do all sorts of interesting things in a middlewear hook.